# How to take advantage of enum string in Swift 2 or greater?

Tags: ios, enums, swift2

So bellow image shows my buttons in the app. I have enum for different choices like this

```
enum Legal: String {

    case Term = "Terms Of Service"
    //Link: WWW.google.com/Terms
    case Licenses = "Licenses"
    //Link: WWW.google.com/License
    case Privacy = "Privacy policy" 
    //Link: WWW.google.com/policy 
}
```

[image: These are my three buttons.]

I want to know if there is an efficient way to store links instead of storing it in variable. I don't have much knowledge about swift memory management, but I do know there is a way we can get away without having to store those links in heap using ENUMS. May be have a function in enum or something.

Currently I am just passing what button title is and returning the link like accordingly

```
func getLinke(legal: String) -> String {

    if legal == Legal.Term.rawValue {

        return "WWW.google.com/Terms"

    } else if legal == Legal.Licenses.rawValue {

        return "WWW.google.com/License"

    } else if legal == Legal.Privacy.rawValue {

        return "WWW.google.com/policy"
    }

    return ""

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You totally can store those link in your enum, if that's what you need, add this in your enum:

```
var link: String {
    get {
        switch self {
        case Term:
            return "WWW.google.com/Terms"
        case Licenses:
            return "WWW.google.com/License"
        case Privacy:
            return "WWW.google.com/policy"
        }
    }
}
```

then can call it like this:

```
let term = Legal.Term
let url = term.link
```

Comment: Little nitpick: they are not "stored" in the enum (that is impossible), they are created each time the getter is called.

Comment: So does this provide better performance memory wise than what I currently have? I want to know in detail if possible! I want to have it where I pass string and get the link back from enum rawValue functionality!

Comment: It doesnt give you better performance or memory wise than what you are having (it's still generating on every getter), but it will just help you arrange your code better, and you dont need to pass the rawValue param again, if you want totally making them constant, then you also can put enum in enum, though i prefer this way (more enum mean heavier on creating, lighter on using, while this is lighter on creating and generate if you call)